# Can C#'s HttpClient accept cookies with a path?

Tags: c#, cookies, openid-connect, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = false,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true
};

return new HttpClient(handler)
{
    Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan
};
```

I'm using OpenID Connect with ASP.Net Core which returns a correlation cookie like this:

```
cookieHeader = "correlation=ABCDEFG; path=/signin; secure; HttpOnly";
```

I make my call to the site:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage msg = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
```

And get redirected to the OpenID server. However, `HttpClient`'s cookie container doesn't contain any cookies. If I manually add an identical cookie to the response modifying only path to equal `/` e.g.

```
cookieHeader = "correlation=ABCDEFG; path=/; secure; HttpOnly";
```

Then the cookie appears in `HttpClient`'s `CookieContainer`. I don't want to have to modify ASP.Net Core base OpenID functionality to change the cookie paths so `HttpClient` will pick up the cookies and I can authenticate. Is there a way to make `HttpClient` save off cookies with paths specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a by-design silent failure. Trying to add these cookies manually yields a `CookieException`. It looks like ASP.Net Core's OpenID Connect implementation relies on an RFC that supersedes the one .NET Framework currently implements. In RFC 2109 (.NET Framework), you can't set a cookie with a path that is not part of the current request while .NET Core (per RFC 6265) does permit and even rely on this behavior. I guess it'll be manual cookie storage for now.

[Source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30991)